# update sharepoint list item based on title field

Tags: list, caml-query, updatelistitems

I have used server object model to update list item based on title field and used below code

```
SPList list = web.Lists["ListName"];

SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(new SPQuery()
{
    Query = @"<Where>
                <Eq>
                   <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                   <Value Type='Text'>objdocument.title</Value>
                </Eq>
              </Where>"
});

foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
    item["Properties"] = objdocument.empID + objdocument.proID 
    item.Update();
}
```

I have debug the code and debugger is not entering in foreach loop.
Can anyone please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update this

```
<Value Type='Text'>" + objdocument.Title + "</Value>
```